# For Protractor e2e tests... Executing method is unstable: Clicking on a button three times

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, protractor

The following method handles the event.

```
exports.movingTowardsNextInstanceStage = () => {
  const nextInstance = manipulations.getDomObject('instance-tab-phases-buttons-next-instance', 'id'); // Next Approval Stage Button

  nextInstance.getText().then((text) => {
    if (text.includes('WEITERLEITEN AN TL')) {
      browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(nextInstance), TIMEOUT, 'taking too long to be clickable');
      nextInstance.click();
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });


  nextInstance.getText().then((text) => {
    if (text.includes('WEITERLEITEN AN LSM')) {
      browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(nextInstance), TIMEOUT, 'taking too long to be clickable');
      nextInstance.click();
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

  nextInstance.getText().then((text) => {
    if (text.includes('FREIGABE')) {
      browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(nextInstance), TIMEOUT, 'taking too long to be clickable');
      nextInstance.click();
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
};
```

Background info: There is one button (nextInstance) that must be clicked three times, in order to activate another button. To keep it short... After each button press a loader appears, a few components are activated and deactivated and so on, also it takes about 2-3 secs until the button is clickable again. During those three second the button is disabled.

I have tried other ways of clicking a button x times.
Using Array.forEach,
using setInterval with a given number of repetitions and delay,
setting implicit waits between each event (click) (this one actually worked).

I want to avoid using implicit waits.

I know I haven't defined the context too well, but looking at my code and my intention, is there any way it could be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding correctly that, 'WEITERLEITEN AN LSM' is expected to show up after the preceding click (the click after 'WEITERLEITEN AN TL')?

If so, your code doesn't currently wait for the nth click before checking the n+1th text, and what you need is promise-chaining. `.catch`, just like `.then` returns a new Promise that you can wait on.

Also, browser.wait returns a Promise that you need to wait on, as well.

So, something like:

```
  nextInstance.getText().then((text) => {
    if (text.includes('WEITERLEITEN AN TL')) {
      return browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(nextInstance), TIMEOUT, 'taking too long to be clickable')
      .then(() => nextInstance.click());
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .then(() => nextInstance.getText()).then((text) => {
    if (text.includes('WEITERLEITEN AN LSM')) {
      return browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(nextInstance), TIMEOUT, 'taking too long to be clickable')
      .then(() => nextInstance.click());
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
  // ...
```

But if an error from the nth click should prevent the n+1th click, you should also leave out all but the final `.catch` call.

And you might consider using async/await. It's more intuitive than Promise-chaining.